# create a cubed bookcase

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for a while and have tried a few things that didn't work, but I would like to create a stationary cube looking bookcase using css.
Anyone have some pointers on how I can do this?
I have included a picture of what I want to create.

Thanks

[image]

```
 .scene {
   margin: 100px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;

   perspective: 600px;
 }
  .cube {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }     
 .cube-face {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.8;
 }
 .cube-face-front {
   background: yellow;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 } 
 .cube-face-back {
   background: orange;
   transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 } 
 .cube-face-left {
   background: green;
   transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 } 
 .cube-face-right {
  background: magenta;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 } 
 .cube-face-top {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 } 
 .cube-face-bottom {
  background: red;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
 }


<div id="bookshelf" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="scene">
        <div class="cube">
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-front"></div>
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-back"></div>
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-left"></div>
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-right"></div>
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-top"></div>
            <div class="cube-face  cube-face-bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good starting point is google for some 3d css cubes, and apply borders, inner shadow and outer shadows. But this won't be browser agnostic, though it should work in most modern browsers

Comment: I have been trying to use a cube but can't get it lined up like a box.  Basically I a square with 2 sides, a top and a bottom.  I can do the rest just can't figure out the box.

Comment: I can't help without seeing your code. Read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/), if you still have problems, post your code.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I just followed that tutorial and did everything up to the point just before fixing the perspective.  It shows an example where you see the outsides of the middle square, but I just get the square.  I will post what I have... Thanks again

Comment: Try this http://dabblet.com/gist/ffba98bd8485a0dc2b80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this :

[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/ffba98bd8485a0dc2b80)

[image]

Markup:

```
<div id="bookshelf" class="container-fluid">
    <!--top-->
    <div class="scene text-center">
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scene text-center">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scene">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scene text-center">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <!--bottom-->
    <div class="scene text-center">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
 *{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0}

:root{
    background: #ececee;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative
}

.text-left{text-align:left}
.text-center{text-align:center}
.text-right{text-align:right}

#bookshelf{
    width: 720px;
    height: 940px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -240px #bbbbbb
}

.scene{
    width:100%;
    display:bock;
    clear:both;
    position:relative
}

.cube{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32.6%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 4px solid #f1f3f2
}
.scene:nth-child(even) .cube{
    width: 30.9%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

.scene:last-child .cube{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 64px #BABABA;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.scene:last-child .cube:first-child{
    border-bottom: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-left: 20px solid #F0F0F0;
}
.scene:last-child .cube:last-child{
    border-bottom: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-right: 20px solid #F0F0F0;
}

.cube:before,.cube:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
}

.scene:last-child .cube:first-child:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 106px;
    background: #f1f3f2;
    }
.scene:last-child .cube:first-child:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-24px;
    left:-20px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    border-right: 22px solid #f1f3f2;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; 
    }   
.scene:last-child .cube:last-child:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 106px;
    background: #f1f3f2;
    }
.scene:last-child .cube:last-child:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-24px;
    right:-20px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    border-left: 22px solid #f1f3f2;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; 
    }

.scene:last-child .cube:nth-child(2){
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 64px #BABABA,inset 0 -18px #E0E0E0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You copied the articles SCSS and replaced the variables with the set width. There is a lot more to SCSS than variables, one of which is maths:

```
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 150px/2);
```

This line is invalid CSS, you can't do division in css without the `calc()` function. and even that doesn't work in all styles.

Change it to:

```
transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 75px);
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/bqbm610v/)